# Browserify doesnt work with function?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

Hi I'm having a problem with browserify, I did `browserify main.js > bundle.js` everything work until it hit function. Now I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: search is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:30)
```

Here is what is on my main.js:

```
function search() {
[..] trigger stuff
}
```

And on my html file I have:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
<button class="ui button" onclick="search()">
```

Else is just design and title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to export a function to be called from outside the bundle (e.g. in an `onclick` handler), the simplest thing to do would be something like this:

```
function search() {
  ...
}
window.search = search;
```

An alternative to the simple, `window`-based solution is the [`--standalone` option](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/readme.markdown#methods). In your `main.js`, you would do something like this:

```
function search() {
  ...
}
exports.search = search;
```

And you would build the bundle with a command like this:

```
browserify main.js --standalone MyApp > bundle.js
```

And your `onclick` handler would be:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
<button class="ui button" onclick="MyApp.search()">
```